# Jenkins : Extract data from Jira curl

Tags: json, jenkins, curl, groovy, jira

I use a curl to get the status of a Jira issue :

```
result = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """curl -D- -k -u $JIRA_LOGIN:$JIRA_PWD -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" $url""")
```

This returns a String like :

```
{"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations","id":"*****","self":"*****","key":"*****","fields":{"status":{"self":"*****","description":"Issues in development","iconUrl":"****","name":"DEVELOPMENT","id":"10400","statusCategory":{"self":"****","id":4,"key":"indeterminate","colorName":"yellow","name":"In Progress"}}}}
```

How I can extract the data "DEVELOPMENT" in this string ? I try to parse it in JSON but it's not working :

```
status_json = new JsonSlurper().parse(result)
```

with the error "java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.JsonSlurper"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the `JsonSlurper`'s [documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html#:%7E:text=JsonSlurper%20is%20a%20class%20that,as%20parseText%20%2C%20parseFile%20and%20others.):

Jira holds all issue fields under the "fields" key in JSON. So, after you get the JSON, you just need to go to the `fields.status.name` in order to get "DEVELOPMENT" text.

Here's a simple approach:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def issueObj = jsonSlurper.parseText('...') // Your Jira response will be here

issueObj.fields.status.name // It will give you the status' name.
```